# print 2D matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, malloc

I'm trying to create and print a matrix, but I'm getting segmentation fault.

```
int** init_dynamic_matrix (int l, int c);
void print_dynamic_matrix (int** ppints, int l, int c);

int main ()
{
    int** ppints = NULL;
    int l = 6, c = 3;

    ppints = init_dynamic_matrix (l, c);
    print_dynamic_matrix (ppints, l, c);

    return 0;
}

int** init_dynamic_matrix (int l, int c)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int** ppaux = NULL;

    ppaux = (int**) malloc (l * (sizeof (int*)));

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        *(ppaux + i) = (int*) malloc (c * (sizeof (int)));

        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            ppaux[l][c] = 0;
        }
    }

    return ppaux;
}

void print_dynamic_matrix (int** ppints, int l, int c)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            printf ("%d", ppints[l][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `ppaux[l][c] = 0;` --> `ppaux[i][j] = 0;`, --> `printf ("%d", ppints[i][j]);`

Comment: Yes I can see it now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
    {
        ppaux[l][c] = 0;
    }
```

Here's the error: in the first iteration of the outer `for` loop you will execute this , but `ppaux[l]` is not yet initialized, so you get segmentation fault.

You probably meant something like:

```
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
    {
        ppaux[i][j] = 0;
    }
```

Because you just created the `i`-th row of your matrix and you want to se it to `0`

Comment: You're welcome. If your problem is solved, could you please mark the answer as accepted? thanks